# Code will never be executed C

Tags: c, macos

I have this problem with the line where it says if (knightATKC == 2 && knightATKC == 4) i says that code will never be executed. and it won't work properly. If anyone knows how to fix this is will be great. Don't worry about the unused variable you might see, i will use that late on, but now i don't know how to fix the code will never be executed. Sorry for my poor english :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
char enter = 0;
char pNAME[30];
char pGENDER;
int pAGE;
int pATK;
int pHP = 20;
int pATKC;
int knightATK = 3;
int knightHP = 15;
int knightATKC = 0;
int kingATK = 5;
int kingHP = 30;
int kingATKC;

printf("While you are enjoying your breakfast at your house, suddenly you get teleported to a different dimension and no one to be seen except an old man.\n");
printf("\nOld Man: What is your name warrior?\n");
printf("\nInsert name:\n");
scanf("%s",pNAME);
fpurge( stdin );

printf("\nInsert gender (m/f):\n");
scanf("%c",&pGENDER);
fpurge( stdin );
while ( pGENDER != 'f' &&pGENDER != 'm' )
{
    printf("\nInvalid entry, please try again.\n");
    printf("\nInsert gender (m/f):\n");
    scanf("%c",&pGENDER);
}

printf("\nOld Man: Now how old are you young warrior?\n");
printf("\nInsert Age:\n");
scanf("%d",&pAGE);
fpurge( stdin );
if ( pAGE < 18)
{
    printf("\nOy mate! No stalker!\n");
    printf("\nTeleporting back to reality...\n");

    return 0;
}

if ( pAGE > 80)
{
    printf("\nNo oldies allowed!\n");
    printf("\nTeleporting back to reality...\n");

    return 0;
}

printf("\nOld Man: Welcome warrior I fear the knights has taken over our kingdom, and you, %s, are the only one who can save us.\n",pNAME);
printf("\n%s: How am I suppose to do that?[Enter]\n",pNAME);
if (enter != '\r' && enter != '\n') { enter = getchar(); }
printf("HI");

while (pHP != 0 && knightHP != 0)
{
    pATK = 5;
    knightATK = 3;

    knightATKC = ( rand()%5);

    if (knightATKC == 2 && knightATKC == 4)
    {
        printf("The knight swings his sword at %s",pNAME);
        printf("T\nhe knight hits %s for 3HP\n",pNAME);
        pHP = pHP - 3;
    }
    else if (knightATKC == 3)
    {
        printf("\nThe knight slashes his sword at %s\n",pNAME);
        printf("\nThe knight critically hit %s for 5 HP\n",pNAME);
        pHP = pHP - 5;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThe knight swings his sword at %s\n",pNAME);
        printf("\nThe knight fails to hit %s\n",pNAME);
        printf("\nPress [Enter] to attack\n");
    }

}}
```

Comment: If you want the code to be executed, don't require a condition that will never be true!

Comment: @DiegoBasch Sometimes developers make simple coding mistakes. Sometimes there is confusion. Sometimes we give the person the benefit of a doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is self-explanatory. `knightATKC == 2 && knightATKC == 4` means `knightATKC` is simultaneously 2 and 4, which is impossible. Perhaps you meant `||` (Boolean or) instead of `&&` (Boolean and)?

Answer (score 3):

Bad statement:

```
if (knightATKC == 2 && knightATKC == 4)
```

This entire if statement can never be true because the `&&` operator is "and" so both the first comparison and the second must be true. But if `knightATKC` is equal to `2` then knightATKC can not be equal to `4`.

Probably what you want is "or"

```
if (knightATKC == 2 || knightATKC == 4)
```

If either is true.